# jQuery: function assigned dynamically is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented a menu with jQuery where the items and the functions are assigned dynamically. [This code works](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/dzSRR/20/).

But since I need to hide the menu when the option is clicked, I changed

```
p.click(funcs[i].f);
```

to

```
p.click(function(){
    menu.hide();
    funcs[i].f;
});
```

as in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/dzSRR/21/),but I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'f' of undefined` because the variable i is out of bounds. how to fix this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    (function(i){$('<p />', {
        'style' : 'cursor: pointer',
        'text' : funcs[i].title,
        'click' : function(){
            funcs[i].f();
            menu.hide();
        }
    }).appendTo(menu)})(i);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dzSRR/22/).

The above passes the `i` variable into the inner scope, and uses a slightly different (due to personal preference) approach to create the `<p>` elements.

Comment: Thanks, this works, could you clarify `inner scope`?

Comment: I genuinely wish I could, but I don't honestly understand it myself. I *think* I do, sometimes, but then I try and construct an explanation and I fall into self-contradictory attempts and metaphors. So, all I can really do is point you to the explanation in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9054695/82548 and apologise for the lack of useful information here.

Comment: "In JavaScript, scope is the set of variables, objects, and functions you have access to.

JavaScript has function scope: The scope changes inside functions."
(From W3school)

So what David Thomas is saying is that inside the function, `i` is not the same as `i` outside the function (i.e. the `i` of the first line and the last line of his code), hence its "inner scope". It would be simpler to explain if in @DavidThomas 's code the parameter of the function was named with another letter (j or k, for example, or even `inner_i` ;-) ).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
        (function(idx) {
            p.click(function(){
                menu.hide();
                funcs[idx].f();
            });
        })(i);
```